# slow compilations with acro package?

Tags: acro

I am using the `acro` package.

It includes an interesting `foreign` key feature that fits my needs.

I `\input{myacronyms.tex}`, with `myacronyms.tex` contains circa 450 acronyms as described below.

```
\DeclareAcronym{aa}{short = allocation d'actifs,long = allocation d'actifs,tag = jargon ,foreign = Asset Allocation,foreign-babel = english ,foreign-locale = french ,plural-form = allocations d'actifs,}
```

... (400 more like this).

The compilation time seems abnormal (>1 minute on icore 5/miktex/windows) to compile the MWE below.

[image]

Obvioulsy, I first thought the problem came from this long sequence of acronym declaration (I doubt 450 is too much for LaTeX though), but even with a short list, it seems slow, so I think I am probably missing something else.

Could it be my installation ?  if yes, what shall I check ?

Would you have any idea on how to speed things up once I integrated my aconyms to my long document (sigh) ?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

%\makeindex
\makeindex[columns=2, title=Alphabetical Index]

\usepackage{acro}

\acsetup{
    first-style = long-short,
    format/long = \itshape ,
    format/short = \bfseries,
    index/use = true,
}

\usepackage{hyperref}



\DeclareAcronym{aa}{short = allocation d'actifs,long = allocation d'actifs,tag = jargon ,foreign = Asset Allocation,foreign-babel = english ,foreign-locale = french ,plural-form = allocations d'actifs,}

\DeclareAcronym{aapl}{short = AAPL,long = Apple Inc,tag = ticker ,foreign = Apple Inc,foreign-babel = english ,foreign-locale = french ,extra = prix au 09/07/2021 : 143.24 USD,}

\DeclareAcronym{action}{short = action,long = action,tag = jargon ,foreign = stock,foreign-babel = english ,foreign-locale = french ,plural-form = actions,}

\DeclareAcronym{afb}{short = AFB,long = Association Bancaire Française,tag = abbrev ,}

\DeclareAcronym{alm}{short = ALM,long = Asset And Liability Management,tag = abbrev ,foreign = Gestion Actif-Passif,foreign-babel = french ,foreign-locale = english ,}

\DeclareAcronym{am}{short = \ensuremath{\mathcal{AM}},long = gestion d'actifs ,tag = abbrev ,foreign = Asset Management,foreign-babel = english ,foreign-locale = french ,sort = A,}

\DeclareAcronym{AM}{short = FOR TEST,long = FOR TEST,foreign = FOR TEST,}

\DeclareAcronym{amex}{short = AMEX,long = American Stock Exchange,tag = abbrev ,foreign = ,}

\DeclareAcronym{amf}{short = AMF,long = Autorité des marchés financiers,tag = abbrev ,}

\DeclareAcronym{aoa}{short = AOA,long = Absence d'Opportunité d'Arbitrage,tag = abbrev ,foreign = Absence of Arbitrage Opportunity,foreign-babel = english ,foreign-locale = french ,}

\DeclareAcronym{ape}{short = APE,long = Appel Publique à l'\'Epargne,tag = abbrev ,}

\DeclareAcronym{ar}{short = actif risqué,long = actif risqué,tag = jargon,foreign = risky asset,foreign-babel = english ,foreign-locale = french ,plural-form = actifs risqués,}

\DeclareAcronym{asian}{short = asian,long = asiatique,tag = jargon,foreign = asian,foreign-babel = english ,foreign-locale = french ,plural-form = asiatiques,}

\DeclareAcronym{asj}{short = ASJ,long = actif sous-jacent ,tag = abbrev ,foreign = Underlying,foreign-babel = english ,foreign-locale = french ,plural-form = actifs sous-jacent,}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

Just a check

\ac{aa} 

\ac{aapl}

\ac{afb}

\ac{alm}


\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/issues/205

Answer (score 0):

> The compilation time seems abnormal (>1 minute on icore
> 5/miktex/windows) to compile the MWE below.

I tried your code with Texmaker from the latest MiKteX distribution.

No matter, if I select Lualatex+View pdf, or Pdflatex + View pdf, it takes almost exactly 7 seconds. If I delete all your definitions aud their calls, it's may be 1 second faster.

Comment: Thank you for the check! I think the correct answer comes from the author of the package in comment regarding version 3 (not version 2 though) being slow to load the acronym definitions.