LuaTeX compilation takes much longer after upgrade of TeXLive 2020 to 2024; XeTeX runs out of memory
I had been using LuaTeX, installed with TeXLive 2020 to prepare a very large document. I upgraded to 2024 because some files related to biber provided by my Linux distrubtions were no longer compatible with packages provided by TeXLive 2020. I feared that there would be breakage after the upgrade; fortunately that was not the case, but compilation is taking much longer. After the upgrade compilation is ~30 min wheras before it was ~15 min.
How can I determine the cause of this increase in compilation time?
I also switched to compiling with XeTeX because it is thought to be faster than LuaTeX, but compilation stops after generating half of the document due to running out of memory.
What can I do about this?
Thanks.
UPDATE:
I have begun investigating and I think the issue is with the acro package, which underwent a major rewrite after the version included in TeXLive 2020, going from a version 2 series to a version 3 series.
Overleaf also notes "Users of the acro package have reported that version 3 is slow to load acronym declarations." They suggest using a version 2 mode, provided by acro version 3.

well you will have to investigate. You have the code and you know what your document is doing and can check where it spends its time.

@BAK take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604379/slow-compilations-with-acro-package

EDIT:
As far as I am concerned, the solution to my original issue is: using version 2 mode of acro 3 in the TL 2024 installation ALONG WITH the solution provided in the related post that corrects the error resulting from using acro2 mode of acro version 3. With this solution compilation of my actual document is similar to the compilation time before the upgrade, if not faster.
ORIGINAL ANSWER:
I can confirm that compilation with the native version 3 of the acro package is much slower than version 3 of the acro package when used with its version 2 mode. I compiled an MWE, with an acronyn declaration list of a little over 200 acronyms, using native version 3 of acro and using version 2 mode of acro version 3, and timed each compilation with the fish shell time function. The results from fish (164.56 seconds vs. 3.06 seconds) were as follows:
LuaLaTeX with acro3 (native v3 mode):
Output written on main.pdf (7 pages, 14490 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.

________________________________________________________
Executed in  164.76 secs    fish           external
   usr time  163.84 secs    0.00 micros  163.84 secs
   sys time    0.23 secs  667.00 micros    0.23 secs

LuaLaTeX with acro3 in (v2 mode):
Output written on main.pdf (7 pages, 14772 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.

________________________________________________________
Executed in    3.06 secs    fish           external
   usr time    2.87 secs    0.00 micros    2.87 secs
   sys time    0.17 secs  634.00 micros    0.17 secs

In both cases on first compilation, the acronyms were printed in the body of the document in their first appearance form. Printing the acronyms in the acronym list required a second compilation, the times for which are not included in the results shown above.
There was an error produced with the version two mode, however. The error does not block the production of a PDF when compiling in a terminal, and all acronyms are printed in the body and in the acronym list (with two compilation runs). It does block completion on IDEs such as VSCode latex-workshop and vimtex. The error is described in a separate question on TEX StackExchange
The following tex file was used:
\documentclass[]{mweclass}

\input{acronyms.tex}

\begin{document}
\part[Preliminaries]{Preliminaries}

\chapter{Test Chapter with Acronyms}


\section{Test Section with Acronyms}

\ac{RDBMS}

\ac{SASL}

\ac{IMAP}

\ac{NIST}

\backmatter
\part*{[]}
\printacronyms

\end{document}

The following class -- with code related to the acro version not being used for each compilation run commented out -- was used:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mweclass}[2024]

\newcommand{\@classname}{mweclass}
\newcommand{\@baseclass}{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\@baseclass}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\@baseclass}

% version 2 of acro
\RequirePackage{acro}[=v2]
%acsetup for version 2
\acsetup{display-foreign = false}
\acsetup{foreign-format = {\scshape} }

% version 3 of acro (latest)
%\RequirePackage{acro}
%ac setup for version 3
%\acsetup{
%       foreign/display = false,
%       format/foreign = {\scshape}
%}

acronyms.tex:
\DeclareAcronym{RDBMS} {
    short = RDBMS,
    short-plural = es,
    long = Relational Data Base Management System,
    pdfstring = RDBMS
}
\DeclareAcronym{SASL} {
    short = SASL,
    long = Simple Authentication and Security Layer
}
\DeclareAcronym{IMAP} {
    short = IMAP,
    long = Internet Message Access Protocol
}
\DeclareAcronym{NIST} {
    short = NIST,
    long = National Institute of Standards and Technology,
}


\input{acronyms.tex}  ?

@david-carlisle The file has over 200 acronym declarations. Should add that to the post or is there a better way to share it?

there is no point in posting an example that can't be used. Do you need 200 declarations (or a separate file) to show the problem? can't you just delete the input and use a couple of definitions in the main file (similarly it would have been much better not to use a custom class file)

@david-carlisle I have included an acronyms.tex file with only a few declarations that does reproduce the problem.

@BAK Could you take a look at the MWE in the answer to your other question?  it takes what you've done, and puts things into a single file that everyone can copy, paste, and compile.  Do you still have the dramatic slowdown with that file?  When I try to combine your three pieces into one and compile with TeXLive 2020 on Overleaf, I'm not having any trouble.  Can you also edit your code into your question?  This isn't really attempting to answer your question, so it shouldn't be presented as an answer.

@Teepeemm The issue is specifically with TeXLive 2024 NOT TeXLive 2020. When I was using TeXLive 2020, the issue was not present. The acro package underwent a major rewrite after TL. The compilation time with the solution provided in the other post, and with the single file source provided in the answer on that post, was consistent with the numbers in the answer I gave for this question. (Compilation time of the single file MWE using the acro v2 mode of acro version 3 provided by TeXLive 2024 was seconds vs. hundereds of seconds, compared to acro v3 native provided by TeXLive 2024.)

@BAK When I go to the trouble and guess at how to put your three pieces together and compile the "acro version 3" with LuaLaTeX in TeXLive 2024 in Overleaf, it takes about 5 seconds, not hundreds of seconds.  Can you please create a single file that exhibits the problem and edit that into your original question?

@teepeemm Thank you for going to the trouble. All I can do is try to resummarize my experience and the solution that works for me. After replacing my TeXLive 2020 installation, which came with acro version 2.x with TeXLive 2024, which came with acro version 3.x, compilation of my 1000+ page document with 200+ acronym declarations, with each acronym appearing multiple times in the document, took much much, much longer. (continued in next comment)

@teepeemm As suggested by Overleaf, I began using acro 2 mode of acro 3 in the TL 2024 installation. This solved the compilation time problem, but it did produce an error, as described in the related post. This error was solved by the answer in the related post.  (continued in next comment)

@teepeemm As far as I am concerned, the solution to my original issue is: using version 2 mode of acro 3 in the TL 2024 installation ALONG WITH the solution provided in the related post that corrects the error. With this solution compilation of my actual document is similar to the compilation time before the upgrade, if not faster. Now I can get back to actually using LaTeX to write and stop tinkering with it.
